# JavaScript - Checkbox acting like Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am making a JavaScript and HTML project where customers can click a check box for the services they would like done and it will add up the cost for each service on the right hand side.

I am currently using check boxes for each item and need them to act like radio buttons. In the screenshot I included customers cannot have the CQuartz Finest package and the Ceramic Pro Gold Package on their car at the same time.

I can get the check boxes to "uncheck" after it realizes the other one is currently checked but it will not subtract it's self from the total.

If you could steer me in the right direction that would be awesome! I typically code in HTML5, CSS3, Java and C++. I have not done a whole lot in JavaScript yet.

I have the screenshot posted here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlkh4vp70sa39wb/what-we-recommend.jpg?dl=0

Here is the code that I am currently using below:

HTML

```
<div id="gold-package"  class = "one-half-box">
                        <div class="option-parent"><input id ="ceramicProGoldBox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onclick="validateCeramicProGold()" class="paintCoatings"><h2>Ceramic Pro Gold</h2><p style="">$1695.00</p></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro 9H" data-geo="ceramic-pro-9h" href="#">• 4 layers of 9H Glass Shield on all painted exterior surfaces</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Plastic Coating" data-geo="plastic-coating" href="#">• 1 layer of 9H Glass Shield on exterior plastics</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro Wheel &amp; Tire" data-geo="wheel-coating" href="#">• 1 layer of Ceramic Pro Wheel and Caliper Coating on wheels and calipers</a></div>
                        <div id="tooltip" class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro Rain" data-geo="ceramic-pro-rain" href="#" >• 1 layer of Rain on all windows and glass</a></div>
                        <div id="tooltip" class="option-child"><a id="paint-correction" title="Paint Correction" data-geo="paint-correction" description="Test Description" href="#" >• Includes 2 stages of Paint Correction</a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="one-half-box-space"></div>

                    <div id="cquartz-finest" class = "one-half-box">
                        <div class="option-parent"><input id ="cquartzFinestBox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onclick="validateCquartzFinest()" class="paintCoatings"><h2>CQuartz Finest</h2><p style="">$700.00</p></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro 9H" data-geo="cquartz-finest-paint" href="#">• 2 Layers of CQuartz Finest on all painted exterior surfaces</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro 9H" data-geo="cquartz-finest-plastic" href="#">• 2 Layers of CQuartz Finest on exterior plastics</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro 9H" data-geo="wheel-coating" href="#">• 2 Layers of CQuartz Finest on Wheels &amp; Calipers</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Plastic Coating" data-geo="ceramic-pro-rain" href="#">• 2 Layers of Car Pro Fly By is applied to exterior glass surfaces</a></div>
                        <div class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="Ceramic Pro Wheel &amp; Tire" data-geo="light-cut" href="#">• Includes a Single Stage Paint Correction</a></div>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var totalPrice = 0.00;
    var ceramicProGold = 1695.00;
    var cquartzFinest = 700.00;

    function validateCeramicProGold() {
        var elCeramic = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldOption');
        var elCQuartzFinest = document.getElementById('cquartzFinestOption');
        var chkboxCeramic = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldBox');
        var chkboxCquartzFinest = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldBox');

        if (chkboxCeramic.checked == false && chkboxCquartzFinest.checked ==  false) 
        {
          totalPrice = totalPrice + ceramicProGold;
          document.getElementById('options').innerHTML += "<li style='list-style-type: none;padding:0;' id='ceramicProGoldOption'>Ceramic Pro Gold</li>";
          updatePrice();
        }

        else if (document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldBox').checked == false) 
        {
          totalPrice = totalPrice - ceramicProGold;
          updatePrice();
          document.getElementById("ceramicProGoldOption").remove();
        }

        if(chkboxCquartzFinest.checked == true)
        {
            //chkboxCQuartzFinest.attr('checked', false);
            alert("CQuartz is already checked");
        }

        else {}
    }

    function validateCquartzFinest() {
        var elCeramic = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldOption');
        var elCQuartzFinest = document.getElementById('cquartzFinestOption');
        var chkboxCeramic = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldBox');
        var chkboxCquartzFinest = document.getElementById('ceramicProGoldBox');

        if (chkboxCeramic.checked == false) 
        {
          totalPrice = totalPrice + cquartzFinest;
          document.getElementById('options').innerHTML += "<li style='list-style-type: none;padding:0;' id='cquartzFinestOption'>CQuartz Finest</li>";
          updatePrice();
        }

        else if (chkboxCquartzFinest.checked == false) 
        {
          totalPrice = totalPrice - cquartzFinest;
          updatePrice();
          document.getElementById("cquartzFinestOption").remove();
        }

        if(chkboxCeramic.checked == true)
        {
            //alert("Ceramic Pro is already checked");
            chkboxCeramic.attr('checked', false);
        }

        else {}
    }

    function updatePrice()
    {
        document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
    }

    $("#ceramicProGoldBox").change(validateCeramicProGold);
    $("#cquartzFinestBox").change(validateCquartzFinest);

    //$(".paintCoatings").change(function(){$(".paintCoatings").prop('checked',false);$(this).prop('checked',true);});

    //Every checkboxes in the page
    /*$('#coatings input:checkbox').click(function() {
        $('#coatings input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });*/                   
    </script>
```

Comment: Question: Looks like you are calling your 2 functions onclick (from HTML) and on change (end of js using jquery), if you do a console.log('ValidateX'); at the start of your functions, does it fire twice? Just curious.
More to the point: you add the prices already if it works, is there a reason you cannot do the opposite to subtract them as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already make use of JQuery, you can make it yourself a lot easier. Use the data attributes to add the relevant group information to the checkboxes, and use one change event on all check boxes that match a certain selection (in this case, I took all check boxes that have the `paintCoatings` class).

When the change of the check box occurs, the event will uncheck all previously selected checkboxes for this group and will compare an internal state to update the totalprice (and potential options)

I added some comments to the code to make it clear what is happening

```js
'use strict';
var totalPrice = 0;

function updatePrice(totalPrice) {
  $('#totalPrice').html('$' + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
}

function addOption(checkboxItem) {
  var s = $(checkboxItem).data('group');
  $('#options').append('<li id="' + s + '">' + $(checkboxItem).data('option') + '</li>');
}

function removeOption(checkboxItem) {
  var s = $(checkboxItem).data('group');
  $('#' + s).remove();
}

function addPrice(checkboxItem) {
  totalPrice += parseInt($(checkboxItem).data('price'));
}

function removePrice(checkboxItem) {
  totalPrice -= parseInt($(checkboxItem).data('price'));
}

var lastChecked = {};
$('input.paintCoatings').on('change', function(eventSource) {
  // target points to the checkbox that got clicked
  var sender = eventSource.target;
  if (sender) {
    // we have the relevant group of data inside data-group
    var group = $(sender).data('group');
    // select all matching checkboxes of this group
    $("[data-group='" + group + "']").each(function(index, checkbox) {
      if (checkbox !== sender) {
        // and deselect them if they are not the same to this sender
        checkbox.checked = false;
      }
    });
    // if this group had a previously selected checkbox
    if (lastChecked[group]) {
      // remove the price from the total price
      removePrice(lastChecked[group]);
      // remove the option from the option list
      removeOption(lastChecked[group]);
      // remove last selected item
      delete lastChecked[group];
    }
    // if the freshly clicked checkbox is checked
    if (sender.checked) {
      // add the price
      addPrice(sender);
      // add the option
      addOption(sender);
      // save it as the currently active one for this group
      lastChecked[group] = sender;
    }
    // update the price
    updatePrice(totalPrice);
  }
});
```

```css
.option {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  border: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.option h2 {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="totalPrice">0</div>
<div id="options">
</div>
<div class="option">
  <input id="ceramicProGoldBox" type="checkbox" data-group="paint" data-price="1695" data-option="Ceramic" name="vehicle" class="paintCoatings">
  <label for="cermaicProGoldBox">
    <h2>Ceramic Pro Gold</h2>
  </label>
  <p style="">$1695.00</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <input id="cquartzFinestBox" type="checkbox" data-group="paint" data-price="700" data-option="Quartz" name="vehicle" class="paintCoatings">
  <label for="cquartzFinestBox">
    <h2>CQuartz Finest</h2>
  </label>
  <p style="">$700.00</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <input id="ceramicProGoldBox" type="checkbox" data-group="wheels" data-price="150" data-option="19 inch wheels" name="vehicle" class="paintCoatings">
  <label for="cermaicProGoldBox">
    <h2>19"</h2>
  </label>
  <p style="">$150.00</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <input id="cquartzFinestBox" type="checkbox" data-group="wheels" data-price="100" data-option="18 inch wheels" name="vehicle" class="paintCoatings">
  <label for="cquartzFinestBox">
    <h2>18"</h2>
  </label>
  <p style="">$100.00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @likwidmonster You are welcome, I hope it fits your needs enough ;)